# OpenSSL RSA_private_decrypt() creates 2 threads, but doesn't clean them up

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-leaks, openssl

When my process calls RSA_private_decrypt() two threads are being created, but I can't find any way to kill the threads when I want to clean up my library during unload.

My cleanup code is as follows, but it doesn't solve the issue:

```
ENGINE_cleanup();
OBJ_cleanup();
EVP_cleanup();
CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
ERR_remove_thread_state(NULL);
RAND_cleanup();
ERR_free_strings();
```

Has anyone else encountered that problem?

Comment: Have you configured multithreading for OpenSSL? I don't know which platform are you running on, but an example is shown in `\crypto\threads\mttest.c`. You basically have to set two functions - https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/threads.html